# Adjoints in Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

I been trying to figure out if the construction of the isomorphism between $g(W)$ and $f^{*}(W^{*})$ via  $$B_V(v, g(w)) = B_W(f(v),w) \quad \forall v \in V, w \in W $$ described (at least this is what I think they mean) in the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose#adjoint) ,
is meaningfull in a Banach space which is not Hilbert. One reason it wouldn't be the lack of existancee of non-degenrate bilinear forms but this is something which I can't manage to establish. Or maybe there is some other reason?

Comment: I do not see any question in this question.

Comment: There is no need for the space to be Hilbert : you are adding this hypothesis from nowhere. Note: In the infinite case, an Hilbert space is not the same as a Banach space whose norm would come from a non degenerate product.

Comment: The  wiki article is about matrices. A continuous linear operator on a real Banach space may or may not be representable as a matrix $T$ .If it can, I don't know off-hand whether the transpose operator $T*(x)$ is definable  at every $x$ in the space. There is a class called $B*$ algebras (and an important sub-class $C*$ algebras, which have "adjoints"  which act like transposes in some ways,although bilinear forms (inner products) may not be available. This is a broad and deep subject.

Comment: @MikeTex thats my point if the space is hilbert then evertying works out fine. But I think there might be Banach with non-degenerate biliear forms, and I wounder if there are adjonts in such spaces.

Comment: @User2313: The concept you seem searching for goes under the name of [Dual Topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_topology) for a [Dual Pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_pair).